# sh script won't run, (unexpected end of file) but the individual lines execute fine

Tags: shell-script, debugging

Below is what I'm attempting to run on my remote machine, and I'm getting 'Unexpected end of file'.

However, if i take the lines and paste them into the CLI, it executes normally.

```
# if [ -f running.script ] ; then echo 'Script already running.'
> else echo 'Script not running.' ; touch running.script
<ervers_status | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}' | tr -d '\r')
<ervers_status | awk 'NR==2 {print $3}' | tr -d '\r')
> if [ "$sip1" = 0 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 1 UP" ; fi
> if [ "$sip1" = 1 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 1 DOWN" ; fi
> if [ "$sip1" = 2 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 1 IDLE" ; fi
> if [ "$sip2" = 0 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 2 UP" ; fi
> if [ "$sip2" = 1 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 2 DOWN" ; fi
> if [ "$sip2" = 2 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 2 IDLE" ; fi
> rm running.script
> fi
Script not running.
Sip Server 1 UP
Sip Server 2 IDLE
#sh script.sh
script.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file
# cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f running.script ] ; then echo 'Script already running.'
else echo 'Script not running.' ; touch running.script
    sip1=$(cat /var/mand/sipservers_status | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}' | tr -d '\r')
    sip2=$(cat /var/mand/sipservers_status | awk 'NR==2 {print $3}' | tr -d '\r')
    if [ "$sip1" = 0 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 1 UP" ; fi
    if [ "$sip1" = 1 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 1 DOWN" ; fi
    if [ "$sip1" = 2 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 1 IDLE" ; fi
    if [ "$sip2" = 0 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 2 UP" ; fi
    if [ "$sip2" = 1 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 2 DOWN" ; fi
    if [ "$sip2" = 2 ] ; then echo "Sip Server 2 IDLE" ; fi
    rm running.script
fi
#
```

I've included the below capture of my NP++ showing exactly what's in the script.

[image]

Comment: I would suspect one or more of the lines has an invisible character -- probably a trailing `\r`. Or possibly the last line is missing a newline. The final `fi` would be a good candidate. List the script using `cat -vet script.sh` - \r shows up as `^M`, newline as `$`. Cut and paste will probably be removing such characters.

Comment: I agree with Paul, I copied your script and it runs without error.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VTJQzPN.png this is from NP++

Comment: I've added an additional line at the end of the script and it had no impact, same error message.

Comment: You've created or edited the script on a Windows machine. Don't do that. It's quite possibly related to your `sipservers_status` command outputting a status value with a trailing CR too.

Comment: You image .png shows that **every** line ends with `CR LF` which is Windows-speak for `\r\n`. You need to remove every occurrence of CR with `dos2unix`, or `tr`, or your favourite editor.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

**CR LF** line endings needs to be converted to Unix **LF**.

---

> I've included the below capture of my NP++ showing exactly what's in the script.

Actually it is not exactly as shown, each line has an extra control code at the end of each line. You need to remove those.

To remove the Windows file formatting via one of the following methods:

- `vi file` then type `:1,$s/^M/` where `^M` is actually holding control and hitting `v` then `m`.
- Install `dos2unix` and do `dos2unix file`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixed it. And when I said exactly as shown, I meant the screenshot was exactly what it was, not that the screenshot confirmed it was correct. I had no idea carriage returns were windows specific.